# How to store result of math equation to another variable

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write a program to find the highest common factor(HCF) (or greatest common denominator) and lowest common multiple(LCM) of 2 input numbers.

The issue I have is that I'm trying to use the HCF as part of my calculation to find the LCM, but am unable to store it properly into a separate variable. Code is below; the problem part that I know is the issue is right at the very end but I don't know the workaround. Any advice would be much appreciated, thanks.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ExerciseD
{
    class Question2
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number A: ");
            double A = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number B: ");
            double B = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            double X = 0;

            while (A > B)
            {
                A = A - B;
                while (B > A)
                {
                    B = B - A;
                }
            }

            while (B > A)
            {
                B = B - A;
                while (A > B)
                {
                    A = A - B;
                }
            }

            if (A == B)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"The HCF of A and B is: {A}");
                X = A;
                Console.WriteLine($"The LCM of A and B is: {A * B / X}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have an assignment like `X =A` in your code. This is "storing a result in a variable".  It's not really clear what you are unable to do. Behind every "=" you have the meaning of "storing a result".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your value of `A` changes over time, save a copy of `A` in another variable, say `A2`, and use that in the final formula as `A2 * B / X`.

Wait till you learn functions, that'll help organize your code better.

---

A shorter solution can be:

```
// Use temporary variables for backup
int tempA = A, tempB = B;
while (A != B) {
    if (A > B) {
        A = A - B;
    } else {
        B = B - A;
    }
}

// Use dedicated variables for clarity
int HCF = A;
int LCM = (tempA * tempB) / HCF;
Console.WriteLine($"The HCF of A and B is: {HCF}");
Console.WriteLine($"The LCM of A and B is: {LCM}");
```

---

Functional Solution:

```
public int calcHCF(int A, int B) {
    while (A != B) {
        if (A > B) {
            A = A - B;
        } else {
            B = B - A;
        }
    }

    return A;
}

public int calcLCM(int A, int B) {
    return (A * B) / calcHCF(A, B);
}
```

Main code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number A: ");
int A = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number B: ");
int B = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine($"The HCF of A and B is: {calcHCF(A, B)}");
Console.WriteLine($"The LCM of A and B is: {calcLCM(A, B)}");
```

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed and informative response, and for including the functional solution too! Will go learn up more on it